# converting mqtt message to json object

Tags: json, mqtt, ignite-ui, igdatachart

I have mqtt subsciber subscribed for some data
On receiving the data **onMeassgeArrived** will be called back with **message** as a parameter
I want that message to be converted to **json object** and pass the same to **igDataChart** method of igniteUI

By doing that Iam getting object not supported error and client is disconnecting from mqtt broker

Comment: we need a sample of your code that makes the problem

Comment: I used this and it is working fine.. thankyou              console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(message.payloadString);

Comment: Great to see you have solved your problem